# Resiliency implementation with Swagger Codegen?

Tags: api, swagger, swagger-codegen

I love using Swagger Codegen to generate clients for my OAS2.0 services. I am now working on making the client generation part of my CI/CD pipeline. Everything is working great.

I generate the a java resteasy client like this.

```
java -jar %codegenpath%/swagger-codegen-cli-%codegenversion%.jar generate -i %projectpath%/swagger.json -l %language% -o %projectpath% -c %projectpath%\config.json
```

Then my config looks like this

```
{
  "invokerPackage": "BLAH.Client",
  "modelPackage": "BLAH.Model",
  "apiPackage": "BLAH.Api",
  "groupId": "BLAH.Client"
}
```

The one thing I noticed is there doesn't seem to be a way to supply some sort of retry policy and default timeouts. Is this something that I am missing or do I need to modify the existing template to handle this?